# Why is so imposible to center this unordered list which has a jQuery accordion?

Tags: jquery, css

I pretty much tried everything to center `#accordion ul`.

Any suggestions?

Code:

**css:**

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}

    #accordion {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 940px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 25px 0px 0px;
    }

    #accordion ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        display: block;
        height: 200px;
        width: 940px;

        }

    #accordion ul li {
        float: left;
    }

    #accordion ul li a {
        background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0%;
        border-right: 2px solid #fff;
        cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:78px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #accordion ul li.landscapes a {
        background: url(../images/landscapes.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    #accordion ul li.people a {
        background: url(../images/people.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    #accordion ul li.nature a {
        background: url(../images/nature.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }
    #accordion ul li.abstract a {
        background: url(../images/abstract.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    #accordion ul li.urban a {
        background: url(../images/urban.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
        min-width:310px;

    }
```

**php:**

```
<div id="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="accordion">
            <ul>
                <?php // Create and run custom loop
                    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
                    $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)');
                    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
                ?>
                <li class="landscapes"><?php the_content(); ?><></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </endwhileul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #intro -->
```

Reference Image:

[image]

Comment: `#accordion { float: left;..` might be a reason..

Comment: @Avinash - yeah my first thought too when I looked at the screen.

Comment: @Avinash Even if `#accordion` is not floating left the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you reduce the width of #accordion ul, either to auto, or just something much smaller? It looks like its set to 940, and its container is 960px. Also could you could try setting margin: 0 auto, on the ul after reducing its size, or text-align: center for #accordian.

Comment: I think the issue was the accordian couldnt be centered because it was almost the same width as the container, so there wasnt any space left on either side for it to look centered.

Comment: actually it used to be 1280px long. Damn, didn't figured out earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your list ends with </endwhileul> instead of </ul>

Are you trying to center the images within the UL?